# Which is better for full bridge rectifier circuit? MLCC or Electrolytic?

Tags: capacitor, filter, bridge-rectifier, smoothing-capacitor

If I place 100uF multilayer ceramic capacitors at the output of a full-bridge rectifier will there be any problem? Or I need to place electrolytic capacitors? What difference do they make (except size)?

Comment: No, that question doesn't have my answer .

Comment: It's incredible how you can read two multi-page answers in less than 3 minutes after me giving you that link! 
It really does answer your question. Andy's answer has general background and a handy Venn diagram, and Barleyman's answer directly addresses benefits and downsides of ceramic vs electrolytic in power applications. So, frankly, do go back and read them instead of claiming they don't answer your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read the accepted answerer. :(

Answer (score 2):

MLCC will have lower ESR than electrolytics, and as they have no electrolyte to dry out, likely a longer life, especially at higher temperatures.

At the 100 uF size, you can be assured that the MLCC's will have a very high-k ceramic with a vicious voltage coefficient of capacitance. If you use them to their rated voltage, assume that the actual capacitance they deliver will be 30% to 50% of their claimed capacitance. Over-provision for capacitance by 2 to 3 times, and maybe use a significantly higher voltage rating than they will see in service.